# c# panel set auto scroll position causes flickering

Tags: c#, winforms

We are implementing a picture viewer with zoom in based on center of the image with scroll options.

We have used Forms.Panel with a picture box control for displaying the image and auto scroll set to true.

In order to implement zoom we are using inflate function but this will redraw the image to top left:

To bring it to center we are setting the scroll position to center using the following code:

```
Rectangle rc = this.Panel_PicBox.ClientRectangle;
Point ScrollPosition = this.Panel_PicBox.AutoScrollPosition;
int height = (int)(PictureBox_png.Height);
int width = (int)(PictureBox_png.Width);

if (rc.Width < width)
    ScrollPosition.X = (width - rc.Width) >> 1;
if (rc.Height < height)
    ScrollPosition.Y = (height - rc.Height) >> 1;

Point p = new Point(ScrollPosition.X,ScrollPosition.Y);
this.Panel_PicBox.AutoScrollPosition = p;
```

The code works perfectly for bringing the image to center, only problem is we see a lot of flickering when the scroll position is set.

We have tried double buffer method to reduce flickering but didnt work. Please suggest if there is any other method to reduce flickering.

Comment: Have you tried to SuspendLayout at the start of the zooming and only when all is done resumeLayout?

Comment: Not a double-buffering problem.  This happens when you use large images, they get expensive to rescale.  Big ones can take hundreds of milliseconds, you'll see the unpainted control rectangle for a while.  Resembles flicker.  You solve it by rescaling the image yourself so it is an exact fit and doesn't have to be done at paint time.  Use 32bppPArgb for the fastest result.

Comment: @TaW : yes used suspend and resume layout, didn't help with flicker

Comment: @HansPassant : precisely in case of large images, will try if rescaling the image helps.